# Why can't I install Rasa on OSX? "There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate"

Tags: python, pip, rasa

I am trying to run the following command on my macbook inside a virtualenv...

```
pip3 install rasa
```

but when I run I get

```
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting rasa
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/rasa/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available. - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement rasa (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for rasa
```

I tried install openSSL 3 [like this](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation#OS_X) but I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

**Given that you're on Mac** you're gonna have an easier time if you go through `homebrew`

1. **If you do not have Homebrew:**

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

2. **Or if you already have Homebrew installed:**

```
brew update && brew upgrade
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies openssl; brew install https://github.com/tebelorg/Tump/releases/download/v1.0.0/openssl.rb
```

Comment: I would like to solve it without homebrew as that creates more issues for me. I don't mind compiling from source which I have done and install openssl it still has the same issue